# How to stop this while loop?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I'm a beginner in coding and I'm making a simple rpg. I'm currently making a floor with only 4 rooms. I want the game to loop infinitely. I also want the game to prompt the player to enter a valid command when they enter an invalid command, but the while loop repeats infinitely. Can someone give me a fix that a beginner can understand, and maybe some pointers? The while loop is
`while foo(move) == False:`.

```
def foo(m):
    """
    """
    if m.lower == 'l' or m.lower == 'r' or m.lower == 'help' or m.lower == 'pokemon':
        return True
    else:
        return False

print() #Put storyline here
print("You may input 'help' to display the commands.")
print()

gamePlay = True
floor4 = ['floor 4 room 4', 'floor 4 room 3', 'floor 4 room 2', 'floor 4 room 1']
floor4feature = ['nothing here', 'nothing here', 'stairs going down', 'a Squirtle']
currentRoom = 0
pokemonGot = ['Bulbasaur']

while gamePlay == True:
    print("You are on " + floor4[currentRoom] + ". You find " + floor4feature[currentRoom] + ".")
    move = input("What would you like to do? ")
    while foo(move) == False:
        move = input("There's a time and place for everything, but not now! What would you like to do? ")
    if move.lower() == 'l':
        if currentRoom > 0:
            currentRoom = currentRoom - 1
            print("Moved to " + floor4[currentRoom] + ".")
        else:
            print("*Bumping noise* Looks like you can't go that way...")
    elif move.lower() == 'r':
        if currentRoom < len(floor4) - 1:
            currentRoom = currentRoom + 1
            print("Moved to " + floor4[currentRoom] + ".")
        else:
            print("*Bumping noise* Looks like you can't go that way...")
    elif move.lower() == 'help':
        print("Input 'r' to move right. Input 'l' to move left. Input 'pokemon' to see what Pokemon are on your team. Input 'help' to see the commands again.")
    elif move.lower() == 'pokemon':
        print("The Pokemon on your team are: " + str(pokemonGot) + ".")
    print()
```

Comment: You have to actually call the `m.lower` method like this: `m.lower()`.  Functions and methods in python are themselves objects, which you are trying to compare directly to strings

Comment: Should m.lower be m.lower () in foo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In foo you are comparing a function definition, m.lower, to a character. Try m.lower () to call the function.